# Error saying that looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe when using photo_view package

Tags: flutter, photoview

Apparently, I am having this error when I navigate to my photo view page and then back to the previous page.

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.

To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

====================================================================================================
```

I have search for similar problems available in stackoverflow but I just cant find the related ones.

Below is part of the codes to route into the photo view page

```
FutureBuilder(
     future: storage.downloadURL(annData.imagePath[index]),
     builder: (BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData)
        {
          return Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
               child: InkWell(
                onTap: (){
                 Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                   builder: (_) => GalleryWidget(
                    urlImages: snapshot.data!,
                   ),
                 ));
              },
                child: Container(
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      child: Image.network(
                        snapshot.data!,
                         fit:BoxFit.cover,
                       ),
                      ),
                     ),
                    ),
                   );
                  }
               if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                  {
                    return Loading();
                  }
                 return Container();
                },
               );
              }),
             ),
            ] else ...[
             Container(),
            ],
```

And here is my photo view page

```
class GalleryWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String urlImages;

  GalleryWidget({required this.urlImages});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: PhotoView(
              imageProvider: NetworkImage(urlImages),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After entering the gallerywidget page and back to the previous page, my existing functions such as delete or edit are all messed up. Please help me on this issue.

I try changing from stateful to stateless widget and the problems is still the same. Please forgive me as my knowledge on debugging is still at a beginner stage.

Answer (score 2):

So while i was browsing the github repository for photo_view:

there is a comment saying to change the version in pubspec.yaml into this

```
 photo_view:
    git: https://github.com/bluefireteam/photo_view.git
```

after running pubget, i am not getting anymore issues. I hope this can help others.